# There are 2 folders.A and B has 7 txt files.There are 3 files same in two folder.Now need to remove 4 file from B which not there in A

Tags: bash, shell

Shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the path of 1st folder"
read filePath
echo "Enter the path of 2nd folder"
read filePath2

find $filePath $filePath2 -print | sort | uniq

if [[ -f $filePath && -f $filePath2 ]]
then
  while [ $filePath/*.txt != $filePath2/*.txt ]
  do
    rm -rf $filePath2/*.txt
  done
else
  echo "The File dose not exist or file not exist in that path"
fi
```

It is not working. Can you tell me right answer?

Comment: Why _would_ it work?! Firstly, you’re checking that the two directories are _not_ directories (`-f`). Secondly, what do you think `while [ $filePath/*.txt != $filePath2/*.txt ]` does?! Thirdly, if the previous conditions were true, you’d remove _all_ `.txt` files in `$filePath2`.

Comment: your ultimate goal is to remove files of folder-B which are not part of  folder-A right ?

Comment: `[ $filePath/*.txt != $filePath2/*.txt ]` is nonsense, unless there is exactly one txt file under each directory. The *.txt whill expand and you will end up with something like `[ A/x.txt A/y.txt != B/u.txt B/v.txt B/w.txt ]`, which is obviously an illegal argument to the `[` command.

Comment: In addition, I think you should explain in your question the desired behaviour of the program, preferably by illustrating it with an example. Also, if you just say _It is not working_, this does not mean anything unless you explain in what respect it does not work. Does it produce some error message? Does it silently wipe out your hard disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash -e

# get the file list

cd "$1"
for i in *; do
    ! [[ -d "$i" ]] && keep_list+=("$i")
done

cd - >/dev/null
cd "$2"

for i in *; do
    [[ -d "$i" ]] && continue
    keep=

    for j in "${keep_list[@]}"; do
        if [[ "$i" == "$j" ]]; then
            keep=true
            break
        fi
    done

    if ! [[ "$keep" ]]; then
        do_rm=true
        rm_list+=("$i")
    fi
done

# print the list, and ask interactively for confirmation

if [[ "$do_rm" ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "${rm_list[@]}"
    echo
    echo "these file names are not in $1, and will be REMOVED from $2"
    read -rp 'type yes to proceed: ' reply

    if [[ "$reply" == [Yy][Ee][Ss] ]]; then
        rm "${rm_list[@]}"
    else
        echo no files touched
    fi
else
    echo "nothing to remove: all file names in $2 are present in $1"
fi
```

Usage: `./script directory-a directory-b`

Note that this only compares file names, not the actual *contents* of the files. You can compare the files' contents with: `diff directory-a directory-b`

edit: Updated to completely ignore sub-directories, as I think that is generally more useful (than comparing a directory to a file). To include sub—directories, remove the `[[ -d "$i" ]]` tests and add `-r` to `rm`.

Comment: @Biffen, yes I originally had full paths in “usage”, then changed to relative paths w/o addressing that. Thanks. Fixed.